# Is there a code tag to indicate "need improvement" on code comments?

Tags: comments

TODO indicates "task to be completed", FIXME to be fixed etc. Is there a code tag to indicate "need improvement" on code comments?

Comment: Duplicate on SO: [Is there a standard for “???”, “!!!”, “TODO” etc. tags in comments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071732/is-there-a-standard-for-todo-etc-tags-in-comments)

Comment: "Clean Code" recommends not using any of them.

Comment: ^ And when you are in the middle of the development? Theses tags are very useful.

Comment: @user16764 the PEP 350 document I linked to has a signficant list of objections to using them... violating DRY with the tracking tool being a very valid one.  C2 on such comments [FixmeComment](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FixmeComment) along with [TodoCommentsConsideredHarmful](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TodoCommentsConsideredHarmful) and [TodoCommentsConsideredUseful](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TodoCommentsConsideredUseful)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest thing to a document trying to standardize this is the Python [PEP 350](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0350/) - which was rejected as *not* a standard.

The Mnemonics section has a list of various ones used - I hesitate to call any of them "commonly used" beyond "TODO", "FIXME" and "XXX" (which are predefined in eclipse).

Going beyond this, it is local convention of that code base and team.

---

The new question - is there a "need improvement" type code tag.  The best practice would to use the minimal set of tags.  "TODO" indicates a task in the code.  `// TODO this code needs to be refactored` would be sufficient rather than using another `// RFE should refactor` or `// IDEA you know, we should refactor this`.  `TODO` is already recognized by Eclipse, by convention, by [mylyn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626041/mylyn-eclipse-todo-integration).

Comment: I change the question to be more specific about my problem. The right answer now is: RFE or IDEA according to http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0350/